# Install 11.10 on GPT with separate /home partition

Tags: installation, partitioning, gpt

I'm trying to install ubuntu / mint on my lenovo 570. Since it's better to use GPT, i'm trying to use that. I get these problems, either some partitions are misalligned, GRUB doesn't install or it just doesn't boot, just shows some firmware or whatever of the laptop, no grub, no grub error or any sort!

So i wanted some instructions on how to install 11.10 in a GPT with a separate /home partition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This page should have everything you need: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link Tim. Very nice webpage about GTP and why it was made. It actually answered several of my doubts and refreshed some stuff I had already forgotten.